# Plotting curve of Fresnel coefficients

Tags: optics

I am studying the Fresnel equations. I know that the Brewster's Angle can be found when the reflected coefficient:

\begin{equation}
r_{\parallel}=\frac{\tan(\theta_{i}-\theta_{t})}{\tan(\theta_{i}+\theta_{t})}
\end{equation}

is zero.

However, how should I plot this curve? Should $\theta_{i}$ or $\theta_{t}$  be the independent variable? Say it should be $\theta_{i}$, what happens with $\theta_{t}$?

Comment: The transmitted angle follows from Snell's law.

Comment: @Pieter I just thought about this. Using Snell's law yields (suppose $n_{i}=1$) $r_{\parallel}=\frac{tan(\theta_{i}-arcsin(sin(\theta_{r})/n_{t}))}{tan(\theta_{i}+arcsin(sin(\theta_{r})/n_{t}))}$. Is this correct?

Comment: The coefficient is zero when the transmitted and the reflected beam are at right angles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited my comment to correct that. The equation does vanish, but I get something like an inverse sine function. I believe it should look like [this](https://images.slideplayer.com/15/4645456/slides/slide_13.jpg)

Comment: You might find this useful https://www.geogebra.org/m/wKk62nUk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should $\theta_{i}$ or $\theta_{t}$  be the independent variable? Say it sould be $\theta_{i}$, what happens with $\theta_{t}$?

The independent variable is the angle of incidence, $\theta_i$. The transmission angle $\theta_t$ is then obtained from Snell's law,
$$
n_i \sin(\theta_i) = n_t \sin(\theta_t),
$$
as
$$
\theta_t = \arcsin \left( \frac{n_i}{n_t} \sin(\theta_i) \right).
$$

Comment: I used Snell's law, but I obtain a curve that resembles an inverse sine (it vanishes in multiple points). Shouldn't it look like  [this](https://images.slideplayer.com/15/4645456/slides/slide_13.jpg)?

Comment: @IchVerloren You seem to have a global-sign discrepancy, but other than that I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULfGS.png), which is a good match to what it needs to be. Check your plotting carefully. (But note that we're not here to de-bug your code.)

Comment: Forget about that. I just realized the result is in radians. I post this in case someone makes the same mistake. I got what I wanted.